# What can I do to fix my "ValueError" in my Deep-Learning Mario project

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been following a tutorial for how to make a RL Mario agent. I am using the libraries, `gym_super_mario_bros` and `nes_py`, and when I run my code I received an error.

In the tutorial, the guide showed a window with a agent playing mario (random actions, but still mario) and when I ran I received an error
This is my code:

```
import pip
%pip install gym_super_mario_bros==7.3.0 nes_py
%pip uninstall gym
%pip install gym==0.23.1


import gym_super_mario_bros
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT

# Setup game
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)


# Create a flag - restart or not
done = True

# Loop through each frame in the game
for step in range(1):
    # Start the game to begin with
    if done:
        # Start the game
        state = env.reset()
    # Do random actions
    state, reward, done, truncate, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    # Show the game on the screen
    env.render()
env.close()
```

this is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 36
     34     state = env.reset()
     35 # Do random actions
---> 36 state, reward, done, truncate, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
     37 # Show the game on the screen
     38 env.render()

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

Comment: The `step` function as showed [here](https://pypi.org/project/gym-super-mario-bros/7.3.0/) returns four arguments, but you are expecting 5 `(state, reward, done, truncate, info)`, it only returns four `state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())`